# AdMob stealing 3 pixels?

Tags: java, android, layout

I have this layout

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mainlayout"  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
  <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_weight="1">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" adroid:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
     ...
     ...
    </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Ad is added as follow

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById( R.id.mainlayout );
AdView adView = new AdView(...);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,nearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL ;               
mainLayout.addView(adView, llParam);
```

I really can't figure out why there 3 pixels below the ad (shown as thiny white checkers in the image). I think tehre is no doubt about that, but I added the black and white pattern in the image to highlight the region I'm talking about. In the original it is all black.

[image]

Comment: I too noticed this while adding AdMob to my application. I never could find an explanation. So now I'm just living with it. I'm interested to see if someone has any insight on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, a number of ad companies add these "pixels" to their image to keep ad distributors honest, as it were.

A number of companies sell this service ([example](http://www.mobilemarketer.com/cms/news/ad-networks/2895.html)): they give you one-pixel images to add to your advertisements, and then they can track (independently of AdMob) the number of people who loaded your ad by counting the number of times their 1x1 pixel was requested.  So this way, an advertiser can make sure that AdMob isn't inflating the number of views of the ad to get more money out of the advertiser.

This might not be the reason in your particular case -- but it sounds like a reasonable explanation.